# Creating a Windows desktop app not a metro/store app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2012, desktop-application

I realize this may be a misplaced question on this forum but most other forums are less that useless!

I've been searching for tutorials on creating a Windows Desktop program, not a Windows Metro/Store app. All I can find is metro and store.

Can someone point me in the right direction for getting started on this? This is what I have chosen in VS2012:

[image]

vs2012 new windows empty project

I will eventually be importing an API but for now I want to get working on a GUI layout. Any pointers/clarification would be great.

Comment: WPF Application would be best, but if you don't know WPF, it could be a steep learning curve.  Otherwise use Windows Forms Application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create a Windows GUI app, you should use either Windows Forms Application or WPF Application. These are the primary two ways in which Windows desktop applications are created in C#. Note that the controls offered through these are different from one another, and the basic fashion in which the UI is constructed is totally different as well.

Windows Forms is fairly simple, and uses a visual designer to add controls to the form. WPF relies much more strongly on a complex markup based language, XAML, in which the UI is written in code. WPF offers a great deal more options as far as customizing controls and their appearances, but in order to use it to its greatest potential you have to spend a decent amount of time and frustration understanding how binding works within XAML.

Comment: thanks @furkle, much appreciated. I've only had to deal with phones until now

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer No problem! If it was helpful, please don't forget to upvote and select the answer.

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer - If you've developed for Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 then you'll already have a head-start on the WPF side of things, as both use XAML.

Comment: @Tim I assumed he meant iPhone or Android - I felt like if he'd developed for WP he would've already been familiar enough with VS/WPF to know the answer to the question.